# Android : how to get YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT for SSO on GMAIL?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gmail, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement the single sign on using GMail. Trying using this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps sample code. I was unable to get YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT token key.

Here is my main.activity where I am using YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflating the menu resource.
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
  // Start the WebViewActivity to handle the authentication.
  case R.id.login:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    return true;
  // Exit.
  case R.id.exit:
    finish();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

app is while running I am getting this error :

```
  04-02 15:09:12.271: E/Web Console(924): SyntaxError: Parse error at https://mail.google.com/mail/x/cc6i6zigt73b-/?pli=1&f=1&shva=1:1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a google app-engine hosted account, the login URI is:

https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=REDIRECT

Where, `myapp` is your app's name and `REDIRECT` should be set to the domain where you will fetch further authenticated resources from. The cookies will be set accordingly by the authentication mechanism. `https://myapp.appspot.com` is what I use as the `REDIRECT`.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, but I have misread your question. You wish to authenticate using the web-based authentication. I gave you the endpoint for authenticating with the google account on one's phone. For the web-based login URLs, you can use `users.create_login_url()` and `users.create_logout_url()`. More info here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls

Comment: unable to load your link in web browser. throwing 500 server error

Comment: Thanks -- Rohan.. but i want using java or android.. plz can you help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: These are to be run on the backend, not on your android app. If you are talking about GAE's Java libraries, it must be having something similar.

Comment: Hey please help me for this issue.. how to get Endpoint URl? i refer this site https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode